# Determining which method implementation will be invoked (Declared vs Actual type)

Tags: java, abstract-class, declaration

I'm studying for my first Java certification, and I came across a sample exam question, whose answer I don't fully understand. The question asks for the output to the code sample below, and the correct answer, which is easily testable, is "Writing...".

```
abstract class Writer {
    public static void write() {
        System.out.println("Writing...");
    }
}
class Author extends Writer {
    public static void write() {
        System.out.println("Writing book");
    }
}
public class Programmer extends Writer {
    public static void write() {
        System.out.println("Writing code");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Writer w = new Programmer();
        w.write();
    }
}
```

I understand that the distinction between the declared type and the actual type comes into play here. The key line is

```
Writer w = new Programmer();
```

In this case, the declared type (Writer) and not the actual type (Programmer) is determining which implementation of the write() method to call.

I'm wondering why this is the case. Perhaps the answer is as simple as that the declared type always determines which implementation of the object's methods will be called.

But what about a different case? I can, for example, write something like

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and expect to have

```
list.get
```

run in O(1) time--in other words, to invoke the implementation of the get method given by the actual type (ArrayList), not the declared type (List).

Why do these cases seem to be working by different rules? Does it have anything to do with the fact that List is an interface and Writer (in the above example) is an abstract class?

I couldn't find anything on this topic but apologize in advance if this is a repeat.

Thanks!

Comment: You answer is here -
 https://coderanch.com/t/674743/certification/Inheritance
Please make a good use of google.

Comment: There's no difference in either of the cases, both working on the same rule, Dynamic Method Dispatch or Runtime Polymorphism! The actual method to be called will be resolved at the run time using the actual type of the object, not the reference.
Have a look at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-method-dispatch-runtime-polymorphism-java/ to understand this concept clearly